# JSF Ajax in primefaces dialog box updates only when dialog box is clicked

Tags: ajax, primefaces, dialog

I have a problem with primefaces dialog box ajax updation. 
There is a input text inside dialog. I have to update the output label present in the dialog box with the number of words entered in the input text. Number of words is calculated based on the number of commas entered.

```
<p:dialog  id="dialog" header="words" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" appendToBody="true">
   <p:panel id="ppanel">    
        <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:12px">
             <h:outputLabel value="Number of words::" />
             <p:outputLabel id="leng" value="#{bean.leng}" />

             <h:outputLabel for="words" value="Words Attached" />
             <p:inputText id="words" value="#{bean.master}" onkeypress="if         (event.keyCode == 188) { this.onchange(); return false; }" >
                <p:ajax event="change" update=":form:leng" listener="#{bean.updateLeng}"></p:ajax>

            </p:inputText>
          </h:panelGrid>    
        </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

When I press comma( keycode=188) my backing bean is getting called and the leng is getting updated But My output label is not reflected with the new value, But when I click my mouse anywhere in the dialog box the value gets updated, Kindly help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Use RemoteCommand http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml 

<p:remoteCommand name="call" update=":form:leng" actionListener="#{yourbean.onchange}" />

And 

onkeypress="if         (event.keyCode == 188) { call(); return false; }"

Comment: You can also look at p:inputTextarea which has a counterTemplate, you can also change the size to look like a inputText. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputTextarea.xhtml